# Select unique row using several columns unique combination excluding not applicable values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, exists

I have a table with three columns, lets define it and fill it with sample data:

```
   A   |   B   |   C   |
------ | ----- | ------|
  A1   |   NA  |  NA   | 
  A1   |   B1  |  NA   |
  NA   |   B1  |  NA   |
  NA   |   B1  |  C1   |
  NA   |   NA  |  C1   |
```

As we can see combination (A,B,C) is unique. I need to have a select which would select exact one row using parameters :A :B :C. For example:

1) If I have :A = A1, :B = SOME_B, :C = SOME_C. It should select first row because column A has exact match while columns B and C are not applicable.

2) If I have :A = SOME_A, :B = SOME_B, :C = SOME_C. It should not return anything.

First try was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE 
WHERE (A = :A OR A = 'NA') AND (B = :B OR B = 'NA') AND (C = :C OR C = 'NA');
```

This returned first two rows. Wrong, as expected. That is not what I want.

Second try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE 
WHERE (A = :A OR (A = 'NA' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SAMPLE_TABLE WHERE A = :A AND (B = :B OR B = 'NA') (C = :C OR C = 'NA')) AND (B = :B OR B = 'NA') AND (C = :C OR C = 'NA');
```

It works and logic is correct, but for B and C I need to do same stuff. After that I need to modify NOT EXISTS for column A which should include NOT EXISTS for B and C, which also should include NOT EXISTS for column A and so on. I get a loop.

Any ideas how can we write simple SQL for solving such problem? Or I just miss some silly thing?

**EDIT:**

Oh, it's my fault, wasn't able to be clear enought. Let's look into business example (table **TEAM_MATRIX**):

```
COUNTRY|PRIORIT|  TEAM |
------ | ----- | ------|
  NA   |  NA   | GLOB_T| 
  UK   |  LOW  | UK_T1 |
  UK   |  MED  | UK_T2 |
  UK   |  HIGH | UK_T3 |
  US   |  NA   | US_T  |
  US   |  LOW  | US_T1 |
```

Coulmns country and priority can be treated as input parameters. Column team should be treated as output. Several examples:

1) Suppose we have parameters: country = FR, priority = LOW. Then output team should be GLOB_T because there is no such combination FR and LOW. (NA means that we do not care).

2) If country is US and priority is LOW => ouput team should be US_T1 because we have combination US and LOW.

3) If country is US and priority is MED => output team should be US_T because we have combination US and NA (NA means that we do not care).

Is there a way to have SQL which follows this logic?

```
SELECT TEAM 
FROM TEAM_MATRIX 
WHERE (COUNTRY = ?1 OR COUNTRY = 'NA') AND (PRIORIT = ?2 OR PRIORIT = 'NA');
```

Here ?1 - country parameter, ?2 - priority parameter. This does not work, for example combination ((NA, NA) -> GLOB_T) will always be selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Clear as mud. :-(

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)